# How to load sprite png on moves

Tags: javascript, plugins, sprite, assets, phaser-framework

For example, I have idle sprite and I have another files PNG where character is moving, so I need to change sprites on move and if yes how to do something like that(I have also asprite file but IDK how to use it, or IDK I must need plugin to load that)
PS i make that on phaser

I try do load without plugin but that doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would do the same for the moving sprite as for the idle animation. if you have multiple files, you would have to load all of them on `preload` *(with different keys)*, generate the animations, and when you want to play the animation just call the `play` function on the sprite.

For details how the single steps work, check out [this official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/animation/create-animation-from-sprite-sheet#), it shows all steps needed. Execpt the loading from multiple file, but that is just adding one extra `load` line in the preload function

> **btw.**: For more details with sprites checkout [these animation/sprite examples](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/animation), there all pretty good, and cover many different topics issues.